# Where is *official* documentation of base R packages?

Tags: r

For every R package, all official documentation can be found at https://cran.r-project.org/ where each package has a [page with all related documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/)). But base packages like `parallel' don't have such page, or do they? Where can I find official documentation of base packages? Google only finds sources like https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf,  but this is not an official R site.

I am looking for an official comprehensive source where I can find everything related to base R packages.

Comment: I think the link you showed with the PDF for `parallel` is the closest thing to official documentation. It is the same documentation that is bundled with R itself _e.g._ if you were to click on `parallel` in the RStudio packages pane, you'd see that documentation.

Comment: @neilfws the pdf file itself sure is official... but the website stat.ethz.ch is not an official R source, just some mirror perhaps. **I am looking for an official comprehensive source where I can find *everything* related to base R packages.**

Comment: maybe see [The R Reference Index](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html)

Comment: The official documentation is in R itself `help(package="parallel")`. You can access that particular document with `vignette("parallel", package="parallel")`. The R Foundation has not made the choice to create its own separate website for that info. There seems to be little need for it when the information is available elsewhere.

Comment: Not a programming question, this is off-topic here

Comment: I'm voting to keep open because this seems to asking for _official_ documentation and is programming-related. ([link to guidance on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541)).

Comment: You can find the official documentation using R, like `help(package="...")` and the name of the package you want, here `parallel` or using RStudio and the help panel on the right of your screen (generaly) and search for "parallel" and see the different result.